# Javascript/jQuery - retain hover event when pointer-events:none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to build a web app with an input box that users can type into. When certain strings are recognized, I'd like the user to be able to hover over them to cause a certain action to take place.

However, since I'm using an

```
<input type="text">
```

to collect the user's typing (instead of a contenteditable div, due to its lack of browser compatibility), I can't put child divs or spans into the textbox itself. Instead, I'm forced to overlay divs on top that can trigger the :hover or .hover() events.

The problem comes here - if I want the user to be able to click on the textbox beneath those overlaid divs, I have to set them to have

```
"pointer-events:none;"
```

This breaks the hover event trigger functionality entirely.

I've checked several similar questions, but none match my problem since none are focused on input elements underneath... If this was an image or some other element underneath, it'd be relatively easy to use javascript/jQuery to pass the click events through to the lower element manually (where click location doesn't matter).

jsFiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/eBnmw/

(works in chrome and safari, not sure about IE)

Any suggestions?

Comment: put a clear div over all, call input.focus() when that div is clicked...

Comment: also, contentEditable has widespread compatibility , even on mobile now...

Comment: Thanks dandavis - but like I mention above, the focus() call gets  more complicated when it's an input underneath, since the location of the click (i.e., what letter they're clicking on) matters as much as the fact that it's getting focus... Also, that's good to know about contenteditable. I couldn't get it to work in safari. I'll do more research on that.